# How to launch a shortcut from the explorer window I am in/ or folder I click on? to copy what is in

Tags: windows, batch-file, shortcut

I am looking for a way to start a shortcut to a batch file using as start directory the folder I select with my mouse/or the folder I am in, and launch it with a keyboard shortcut.

example:
My .bat is in whatever directory, same for my shortcut file, which has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>maj</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> as key shortcut. (this already works the way I want)

I click/navigate to the folder I want to execute the .bat, and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>maj</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.
Then I want to go in an other folder and do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>maj</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> again to use the .bat on this folder.

The problem is, it always starts in the folder where the .bat file is.

I already tried to clear the "start in" box from shortcut properties, but I can't replace it with what my mouse targeted, I feel like I could do it with the "target" box, but I don't know how since my target will never be the same folder.

The end goal is to copy some files from some folders to an other folder on the desktop, this works fine if I drop the .bat file in the 1st folder but I don't want to do that every time, it kills the efficiency.
(working on win10)
I am sure some of you has some kind of trick for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my simple test, if I clear the "Start in" field then `%cd%` in the batch is correct when I manually `start` the shortcut from another directory.

However, this is not going to work if you set a keyboard hotkey because there is no context, the current directory will always come from the main Explorer.exe.

The correct way to do this is:

- A) Put the batch or shortcut in the "Sent To" folder.
- B) Register the batch file as a context menu item:

  ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\MyBatch\command]
   @="\"C:\\myfiles\\test.cmd\""
  ```

  (Right-click on an empty area inside the folders file list, `%cd%` will be correct).

Comment: Thank you, it is working perfectly with your method.
I added the batch file as a context menu item like you wrote, and placed my batch in a folder which is referred to in the registry.

The shortcut file itself is now useless. I did not need to place the batch in the "send to" folder since my script prompts the user to choose a name and create the folder on use, then copy the files I need in it.
I did not know you could use the right-click menu like this, but it is perfect.

Thank you also to Jason Aller for editing my mistakes.